# Position text in horizontal center of parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header which contains two buttons and a "logo". The two buttons should float right and left, relative to the browser and the "logo" should be in the absolute horizontal center, again relative to browser.

It all worked out fine until I realized that the logo sits in the center between the two buttons which differ in size, putting it off-centre.

Here's my code: [Clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/KLTNx/)

I tried some absolute positioning, but it did nothing, probably due to ignorance on my part.

```
#head {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you tried to use the 'text-align: center' on the parent container to make this work.  And it is working, except that it's centering all 3 of those elements as a whole.  You can see that here if you remove the floats: http://jsfiddle.net/aHP6D/1/.

So, one option would be to position the buttons absolutely, thus taking them out of the normal document flow.  This means the only `<span>` that's left (and not absolutely positioned) is the one you want centered.

You can see that working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aHP6D/2/

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!
While I was trying to do this, I read that an element with absolute positioning is ignored when positioning other elements (or something along those lines) and I thought I should use it for the logo.

Now it actually makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

To center something, just set the margin to auto:

```
#head{
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

to center it completely:

```
#head{
  position:relative:
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `#head`’s `position` to `absolute` and `left` property to `50%` will center its left side. Setting its `margin-left` property to negative half its width will pull it back to the center.

```
#head {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/exs78/ for an example.